# Convert an integer from a scraped string in a database in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe, web-scraping

I am struggling to find a way to convert a string that has both numbers and letters into just a number in R. I web-scraped data, and now want to convert one column from a string into a number. The last column of my df, Clean.data$Drafted..tm.rnd.yr currently reads like, "Arizona / 1st / 5th pick / 2011". I am trying to extract the pick number, so for that example, I would want to just extract "5". Is there anyway to do this? I am fairly new to R.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

years <- 2010:2020

urls <- paste0(
  'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/draft/',
  years,
  '-combine.htm')

combine.data <- map(
  urls,
  ~read_html(.x) %>% 
    html_nodes(".stats_table") %>% 
    html_table() %>% 
    as.data.frame()
) %>%
  set_names(years) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "year") %>% 
  filter(Pos == 'CB' | Pos == "S")

Clean.data <- combine.data[!rowSums(combine.data == "")> 0,]
```

This is my code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract the relevant number from the data.

```
Clean.data$pick_number <- as.integer(sub('.*?/\\s(\\d+).*', '\\1', 
                                     Clean.data$Drafted..tm.rnd.yr.))
Clean.data$pick_number

#  [1] 5 2 5 3 1 1 4 1 5 3 3 4 1 4 3 5 3 2 2 4 3 1 5 1 5 7 2
# [28] 5 3 7 1 2 3 4 7 7 2 3 3 5 3 5 7 3 2 2 5 3 5 4 4 6 1 3
# [55] 6 7 6 4 2 4 3 2 6 5 2 3 5 3 1 2 2 4 3 1 3 6 4 6 2 2 2
# [82] 4 1 6 3 3 4 5 2 1 3 3 7 3 1 2 1 4 4 5 3 1 2 4 3 2 7 3
#[109] 3 4 5 2 4 5 1 7 2 6 5 4 2 6 4 4 5 4
```

This extracts the digits after the first `"/"`.